# MySQL Query to retrieve data from two tables even no data found in second table

Tags: mysql, join

I want to fetch a data from two tables even if the second table has no data. I need empty values for no data.

For e.g. table 1 has the fields

- id
- name
- password

table 2 has

- id(foreign key refer id from table 1)
- f1
- f2
- f3

Some time table 2 doesn't have the value for a particular user. For that I need the null values.

Here I give sample input and expected output

```
table1
id name password
1  nam1  pass1
2  nam2  pass2

table 2
id f1 f2 f3
1   1  2  3

sample output
id name password f1 f2 f3
1  nam1  pass1   1  2  3
2  nam2  pass2   null null null
```

I need a query to fetch a data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `SELECT` with `LEFT JOIN`

Sample query will be like:

```
SELECT 
    table1.id,table1.name,table1.password,table2.f1,
    table2.f2,table2.f3 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 
ON table1.id=table2.id
```

Comment: idd.. you beat me with 20 secs :)

Comment: Thanks Sergey Kudriavtsev .. Its works. Now i have one more doubts suppose i want to fetch only a particular data from those table for example i want to show only 2nd data then what i have to do?

Comment: Please clarify what do yu mean by "Only 2nd data" here. If you need only data from table 2 then you just need to remove all not needed fields from SELECT part of query - so it looks like `SELECT table2.f1, table2.f2,table2.f3 FROM ...`. If you need to select only one row for every two rows in table then you may add a following clause to the end of query: `WHERE table1.id % 2 =0`.

Comment: The query you have given will retrieve all rows from the table.. i want to retrieve only one particular row by its id.. i have to pass id value in query to retrieve data

Comment: Then you should add your id value as a parameter for WHERE - so query will look like `SELECT 
    table1.id,table1.name,table1.password,table2.f1,
    table2.f2,table2.f3 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 
ON table1.id=table2.id
WHERE table1.id=%your_id_here%`

Comment: SELECT table1.id,table1.name,table1.password,table2.f1, table2.f2,table2.f3 FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id WHERE table1.id=%your_id_here% .. I tried this query before. it returns data for multiple times...

Comment: Could you please provide an example of such data? To ensure that data is returned only once you may also use `DISTINCT` keyword before a list of fields, like this: `SELECT DISTINCT table1.id,table1.name,table1.password,table2.f1, table2.f2,table2.f3 FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id WHERE table1.id=%your_id_here%`

Comment: Also if you have multiple data rows for a single user in second table then you *will* get multiple rows for sure. To avoid this you'll have to specify what specific row should be returned from second table for user - would it be the first row, the random one or some aggregate function like SUM() or COUNT() should be used? Anyway, it's just a speculation.

Comment: this is working but i get NULL where no data i dont want that

Comment: @DharaPatel: What would you like to get in place of those nulls? If you want to get rid of those rows completely then you can just replace `LEFT JOIN` with `INNER JOIN`. If you want some other value to be shown there instead of NULL, the you can use MySQL `IFNULL` function (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

You want to look to left join and right join